# Is it possible to choose the Radon-Nikodym derivative to be continuous almost everywhere?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I am considering a compact Hausdorff topological space $X$, and the space of complex Borel Radon measures on $X$. Given a measure $\mu$ in this space, the polar decomposition allows us to write

$$\mu = e^{i\theta}|\mu|$$

for some Borel integrable (wrt $|\mu|$) function $e^{i\theta}$. Is it possible to choose this function to be continuous almost everywhere? (If not, when is it possible?)

In general is this possible for measures?

Thanks!

Comment: the measure defined by integration against the characteristic function of a fat cantor set in $[0,1]$ with respect to Lebesgue measure is the first counterexample that comes to mind

Comment: Given a positive measure $\lambda$ you are free to *define* $\mu= e^{i\theta} \lambda$, aren't you?

Comment: @user363464 Thanks! Now I am wondering what happens in the polar decomposition

Comment: @Jochen In our case, $e^{i\theta(\cdot)}$ is just a notation used for a Borel function $f$ that maps from $X$ to the circle group. It is not a constant.

Comment: I think what @Jochen means is that you can choose a function $\theta$ so that $e^{i\theta}$ is discontinuous on a set of total variation $0$ w.r.t. $\lambda$, and then define the measure $\mu$ by $$\mu(E)=\int_{E} e^{i\theta} d\lvert\mu\rvert$$